# If $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable, then $E(X|\mathcal{G})=X$ . Why is X will be constant on the atoms of $\mathcal{G}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation, conditional-expectation

[image]
[image]

I have no idea why it said Since $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable., then it is constant.

Why would be each atom(means a set?) in $\mathcal{G}$ would be intervals? Since $X$ is measurable means $\{w:X(w)\geq a\}\in\mathcal{G}$

Comment: "$X$ is constant on the atoms of $\mathcal{G}$" (what the quoted text says) is very different than "$X$ is constant" (what you've asked in both the title and the body).  Do you understand the distinction?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I also do not understand why it is constant on the atoms

Comment: Let $A \in \mathcal{G}$ be an atom and let $r \in \mathbb{R}$.  Can you say anything about $A \cap \{\omega : X(\omega) \geq r\}$ as $r$ varies?  Can it ever be a nonempty proper subset of $A$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, I think it can be a non empty proper subset of $A$

Comment: That's incorrect.  You need to review what it means for $A$ to be an atom of $\mathcal{G}$ (keeping in mind that since $X$ is measurable, $A \cap \{\omega : X(\omega) \geq r\} \in \mathcal{G}$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring I see, I thought an atom was just another name for a set in sigma algebra, now I see by definition those collections of sets cannot have nonempty proper subsets in the sigma-algebra, and this collection also partitions the sample space. In the sense that each atom has in the least size. Even though, I still do not get the point.

Comment: Assume $X$ takes more than one value on $A$, say $r_1, r_2$.  Do you see what happens when you set $r = \frac12(r_1+r_2)$ in $A \cap \{\omega : X(\omega) \geq r\}$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring will be a Non-empty subset of $A$, and this is not in $\mathcal{G}$, contradiction to the measurability of $X$